# Why if static method don't involve in polymorphism(late binding) I see error that static method cannot be overridden

Tags: java, inheritance, static, polymorphism, overriding

please consider following code:

```
class A{
    public static void m(Number n){
         System.out.println("Number A");
    };
}
class B extends A{
     public static int m(Number n){
        System.out.println("Number B");
        return 1;
      };
}
```

output:

> java: m(java.lang.Number) in inheritanceTest.B cannot override
>   m(java.lang.Number) in inheritanceTest.A   return type int is not
>   compatible with void

I know that static methods doen't involve in polymorphism hence I infer that overriding is impossible for my code. This compiler message is strange for me.

As I understand that overriding  is part of polymorphism. I prepare for scjp and I am afraid make mistake in familiar question.

Please clarify this issue.

expected behaviour for me - message about overloading error

**P.S1.**

I have read top popular question about static overridden and I didn't found answer(

**P.S2.**
According Pshemo answer:

this code:

```
class Foo{
    public static void m(Number n){
         System.out.println("Number A");
    };
    public static int m(Number n){
        System.out.println("Number B");
        return 1;
    };
}
```

---

outputs:

```
error: method m(Number) is already defined in class Foo
    public static int m(Number n){
                      ^
1 error
```

For me these situations are same. But compiler error is different - strange.

Comment: I'm not sure why the compiler error is about overriding when it should be a wrong overloading.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza yes - I think same)

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I got the same thing with `javac 1.8.0`.  Eclipse just says "the return type is incompatible".

Comment: @ Sotirios Delimanolis http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php and http://ideone.com and idea intellij 12 on local PC

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza I have understood our common mistake. overloading - it is when same signature and different argument list. In my case same signature and same argument list!!!

Comment: Compiler error is misleading, see https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/look_ma_javac_tells_me#comment-1256118438000

Comment: Possibly related: [Why is return-type covariance enforced for hidden static methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30875047)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JLS §8.4.8.3 (Java 8) says:

> If a method declaration d<sub>1</sub> with return type R<sub>1</sub> **overrides or hides** the declaration of another method d<sub>2</sub> with return type R<sub>2</sub>, then d<sub>1</sub> must be return-type-substitutable (§8.4.5) for d<sub>2</sub>, or a compile-time error occurs.

This same rule applies both to instance methods and static methods, since it says "overrides or hides".  Basically, if you have a method with the same name and same parameters, it overrides if it's an instance method, but hides (the inherited method) if it's a class (static) method.  And in both cases, the return type must either be the same or obey the rules for covariance.

Since it's the same rule, most likely there's just one place in the compiler code that checks this rule, and if the rule is violated you're getting the error you're seeing, which I'm sure is a much more common occurrence.  The compiler really should check to see whether it should say "overrides" or "hides", but it looks like they slipped.  Getting error message exactly right is not usually the highest priority of compiler writers--not compared to making sure code that's supposed to compile does so and runs right, and code that isn't supposed to compile doesn't.  So I think this is a deficiency, but a very minor one.

Comment: After this answer I have question Who is more early - jls writing or compiler writing)))

Comment: @ajb Is hiding rules looks like overloading rules? For example I know that I cannot overload method if I change only return typre. I just prepare to scjp

Comment: @gstackoverflow This rule is similar to the overloading rules, but it's not quite the same, because for an inherited method, you *can* change the return type, but only to a subclass of the original return type.  (Or in some other cases involving generic type parameters.)

Comment: Whether the error message says "hides" or "overrides" is a minor issue. The real question is why the rules for overriding (which involves dynamic polymorphism) are being used for hiding (which does not).

Answer (score 6):

Even if static methods can't be overridden they are still inherited so what you are trying to do would lead to situation similar to

```
class Foo{
    public static void m(Number n){
         System.out.println("Number A");
    };
    public static int m(Number n){
        System.out.println("Number B");
        return 1;
    };
}
```

which is wrong because you can't have two methods with same signature but with different return types. Reason why it was forbidden is quite simple... Lets say we have methods:

- `Foo method(){ return new Foo(); }`
- `Bar method(){ return new Bar(); }`

and you would want to invoke them like

```
System.out.println(method());
```

Should result be Foo or Bar? Compiler wouldn't be able to decide.

To prevent this kind of situations compiler forbids overriding/hiding methods with same signature by changing its return types. Only exception is when you are changing return type to more detailed one like

```
class X{
    List<String> m(){...}
}

class Y extends X{
    LinkedList<String> m(){...}
}
```

So it seems that `override` is not best word here. Correct word should be `hide` since static methods can be hidden, not overridden. But it looks like same rules (or at least some portion of them) are used to test if we can hide method as rules for overriding, so in case of problem same error message is shown (about overriding instead of hiding), which can be misleading.

Comment: What is "overriding" in java terms ?

Comment: I am not sure which part of overriding is not clear for you so maybe check this part of official Java tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Comment: for me: overriding is part of polymorphism(late Binding only)

Comment: for me - it is overloading (in your example)

Comment: your code compiler output: **method m(Number) is already defined in class Foo
    public static int m(Number n){**

Comment: @gstackoverflow: Actually, you can not overload like that. The return type is not a part of the method signature.

Comment: @Bhesh Gurung anyway I want to see same errors for my code and Pshemo code.

Comment: my javac returns **HelloWorld.java:12: error: m(Number) in B cannot override m(Number) in A
     public static int m(Number n){System.out.println("Number B");return 1;};
                       ^
  return type int is not compatible with void
1 error**

Comment: @gstackoverflow Actually to prevent situation described by me, compiler forbids changing return type of overridden methods AND hidden methods. Since compiler is doing same test for both cases (overriding/hiding) it also has same error massage which unfortunately includes only overriding.

Comment: @Pshemo Is hiding rules looks like overloading rules? For example I know that I cannot overload method if I change only return typre. I just prepare to scjp

Comment: Even if the signature in the subclass is exactly the same as the signature in the superclass, the compiler still must decide which method to use when the method is used without a class name. Having a rule that prevents changing the return type does not help, so that cannot be the justification for the rule.

Comment: @AlanSnyder Good point. You may be interested in accepted answer here: [Why is return-type covariance enforced for hidden static methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30875047).

Answer (score 2):

I think the compiler error usage of 'override' is misleading here, it isn't applicable.

The [language spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#8.4.8.3) says:

> If a method declaration d1 with return type R1 overrides or hides the declaration of another method d2 with return type R2, then d1 must be return-type substitutable for d2, or a compile-time error occurs.

Here your B method [is hiding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#8.4.8.2) the declaration of A.m:

> If a class declares a static method m, then the declaration m is said to hide any method m', where the signature of m is a subsignature (§8.4.2) of the signature of m', in the superclasses and superinterfaces of the class that would otherwise be accessible to code in the class.

If your B class did not have an m method, then you could call B.m and it would call the m defined on A.

Having B.m is hiding A's version of m. Because you can call a static method defined on a superclass but reference the subclass, that sets up some expectations about the method that are violated by the different return type.

It's hiding and not overriding because if you have a B.m defined, you can still call A.m and get the superclass' version of the method. With overriding it's the runtime type that decides what gets called and how it's called does not matter.

Comment: "Because you can call a static method defined on a superclass but reference the subclass, that sets up some expectations about the method that are violated by the different return type." That sounds the explanation you are proposing involves some kind of "mental inheritance". I would like to know if the original and current Java designers would agree with this explanation.