# Why is return-type covariance enforced for hidden static methods?

Tags: java, jls

This code won't compile because of the `String` return type of the `staticMethod` in `Child`.

```
class Parent {
    static void staticMethod() {    
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    static String staticMethod() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I know that JLS 8 in §8.4.8.3, "Requirements in Overriding and Hiding" says:

> If a method declaration d1 with return type R1 overrides or hides the
>   declaration of another method d2 with return type R2, then d1 must be
>   return-type-substitutable (§8.4.5) for d2, or a compile-time error
>   occurs.

My question is what has been the motivation for this compile-time checking in the specific case of static methods, an example ilustrating that the failure to do this verification during compilation would produce any problems would be ideal.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23573851/829571

Comment: I think this question roughly translates to *Why are static methods inherited in Java*

Comment: There is no static method overriding in Java. The message in misleading. But static method are inherited, and you can't overload  a method with changing only the return type (at least in this case you can have a subclass for the return type, but void has no subtype).

Comment: Ok @assylias, that is the same question, but the first code sample in the answer your are pointing me to doesn't really justify a compilation error, because the compiler is able to resolve the corresponding static method in any way it is declared, `staticMethod();`, `Class.staticMethod()`, `intanceVariable.staticMethod()`.

Comment: @ChetanKinger, I think that your edited title for this question is not quite right, as return-type covariance is actually applicable for hidden static methods, don't you think the original title is the right one, although a little long?

Comment: @JaimeHablutzel You are right. Take a look at the new edit. Makes the title a lot more meaningful and shorter :) Also, I realize now that my answer was not what you were looking for. That being said, the accepted answer just explains how things work internally and how things can break because of the feature. If that's what you were looking for, you need to edit your question to *Why is return type covariance a bad thing for static methods*? rather than *What was the motivation for compile time check of return type covariance in case of static methods*

Comment: @ChetanKinger What about _Why is return-type covariance enforced for hidden static methods?_

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is one of the most bizzare things in Java. Say we have the following 3 classes

```
public class A
{
    public static Number foo(){ return 0.1f; }
}

public class B extends A
{
}

public class C
{
    static Object x = B.foo();    
}
```

Let's say all 3 classes are from different vendors with different release schedules.

At compile time of `C`, the compiler knows that method `B.foo()` is actually from `A`, and the signature is `foo()->Number`. However, the generated byte code for the invocation does not reference `A`; instead, it references method `B.foo()->Number`. Notice that the return type is part of the method reference.

When JVM executes this code, it first looks for method `foo()->Number` in `B`; when the method is not found, the direct super class `A` is searched, and so forth. `A.foo()` is found and executed.

Now the magic starts - B's vendor releases a new version of B, which *“overrides”* `A.foo`

```
public class B extends A
{
    public static Number foo(){ return 0.2f; }
}
```

We got the new binary from B, and run our app again. (Note that `C`'s binary stays the same; it has not been recompiled against the new `B`.) Tada! - `C.x` is now `0.2f` at runtime!! Because JVM's searching for `foo()->Number` ends in `B` this time.

This magical feature adds some degree of dynamism for static methods. But who needs this feature, honestly? Probably nobody. It creates nothing but confusions, and they *wish* they could remove it.

Notice that the way of searching only works for single chain of parents - that's why when Java8 introduced static methods in interfaces, they had to decide that these static methods are not inherited by subtypes.

Let's go down this rabbit hole a little further. Suppose B releases yet another version, with "covariant return type"

```
public class B extends A
{
    public static Integer foo(){ return 42; }
}
```

This compiles fine against `A`, as far as B knows. Java allows it because the return type is "covariant"; this feature is relatively new; 
previously, "overriding" static method must have the identical return type.

And what would `C.x` be this time? It is `0.1f`! Because JVM does not find `foo()->Number` in `B`; it's found in `A`. JVM considers `()->Number` and `()->Integer` as 2 distinct methods, probably to support some non-Java languages that runs on JVM.

If `C` is recompiled against this newest `B`, C's binary will reference `B.foo()->Integer`; then at runtime, `C.x` will be 42.

Now, B's vendor, after hearing all the complaints, decides to remove `foo` from B, because it is so dangerous to "override" static methods. We get the new binary from B, and run C again (without recompiling C) - boom, runtime error, because `B.foo()->Integer` is not found in B or in A.

This whole mess indicates that it was a design oversight to have allowed static methods to have "covariant return type", which is really only intended for instance methods.

UPDATE - this feature might be charming in some use cases, for example, static factory methods - `A.of(..)` returns `A`, while `B.of(..)` returns a more specific `B`. The API designers must be careful and reason about potential dangerous usages. If `A` and `B` are from the same author, and they cannot be subclassed by users, this design is quite safe.

Comment: Woah, this really explains the reason the JLS/compiler are designed that way... and I wasn't expecting to even hear about the flaws of that design :D

Comment: This is the best answer I have seen so far. It would be interesting to consider what a *good* solution would be to the binary compatibility issues you discuss. The current solution is inadequate and, as you state in the update, there are cases such as static factory methods where a subclass designer may want to completely hide and replace the superclass static methods.

Answer (score 1):

`String` is not a subtype of `void`. Now coming to the actual question :

The crux of this limitation is the fact that `static` methods do get inherited in `Java` but cannot be overriden. If we have to find the motivation for compile-time checking of return types of `static` methods, the real question to be asked is *Why are static methods inherited in Java but can't be overriden?*

The answer is simple.

`static` methods can't be `overriden` because they belong to a `class` and not an `instance`. If you want to know the motivation behind this, you can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223386/why-doesnt-java-allow-overriding-of-static-methods) question that already has some answers. `static` methods are allowed to be inherited because there are countless situations where a subclass would want to reuse a `static` method without having to repeat the same code. Consider a crud example of counting the number of instances  of a class :

```
class Parent {
   private static int instanceCount = 0;

   public Parent() {
       ++instanceCount;
   }

   public static int staticMethod() { 
       return instanceCount;   
   }

   //other non-static/static methods
}

class Child extends Parent {
    //.. other static/non-static methods
}
```

`Parent` knows how to count the number of `instances` that were created of itself. `Child` is a `Parent` so `Child` should ideally know how to count instances of itself as well. If `static` members were not inherited, you would have to duplicate the code in `Parent` within `Child` as well.

Comment: If you have `Parent.foo()` static method and `Child.foo()` static method, both with different return types, and then you make a `foo()` call from anywhere, e.g. `Parent.foo()`, `localVariable.foo()` or simply `foo()`, in all these situations the compiler can determine the correct class the static method belongs to, so there is no place for confusion. As long as I believed, static methods where being inherited only for making it easier to call static methods in the parent, instead of a full `Parent.staticMethod` sentence.

Comment: Where there is inheritance, there is code reuse. I highly doubt that the motivation behind inheriting static methods would be so that a few lazy programmers could avoid a few keystrokes. Also, the compiler cannot infer a call like `foo()` from anywhere other than the parent or child class. Last but not to the least, nowhere do I say that `static` methods get inherited to avoid confusion. They are `inherited` for code reuse and that's the point I am trying to make.

Comment: Can the downvoter please let me know what is wrong with my answer?

Comment: In the case of the simple call to `foo()`, of course it has to be made from the parent or child, or with a static import, but my point is that the compiler  can for sure determine the class that static method call belongs, so I can't see the real reason for the JLS/compiler to disallow a sample code like the one I posted in my question.

Comment: @JaimeHablutzel Before I proceed to respond to your comment, I would like to know whether it was the reason why you downvoted my answer?

Comment: @ChetanKinger I haven't downvoted, I always provide the reason as a comment when I do it, except when the answer is really really low quality

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong with how the compiler treated you, be your methods static or otherwise. Just the next couple of lines in the documentation say:

> This rule allows for covariant return types - refining the return type of a method when overriding it. 
>   If R1 is not a subtype of R2, a compile-time unchecked warning occurs
>   unless suppressed by the SuppressWarnings annotation (§9.6.3.5).

Clear. R1 must be a subtype of R2 like `Integer` is to another `Integer` or to `Number`. `String` is not subtype of `void`.

Documentation says: "compile-time unchecked warning occurs...". But what I noticed is that a full-fledged compilation error awaits.

Inheritance still works as expected. Remove your child method and you 'd have access to the parent's, static or otherwise.

Comment: I'm looking for the motivation to make the compiler work that way, see my comments on the original question and @Cheetan Kinger answer.

Comment: I believe Cheetan's original answer didn't contain the first key sentence, it was added (with an edit) sometime after my post so I got nothing to look at there. As to your question, I don't get what you're looking for by "motivation". I verified this by coding and found that there was no difference between static or non-static method when it comes to inheritance behaviour, which is expected and less confusing this way. Either that, or I still don't get you.

Comment: @mohsenmadi The first sentence that you are talking about is irrelevant if you can look beyond it and understand what the OP is actually asking. I am sure the OP did not ask *is String a subtype of void*?. You have everything to look at in my answer other than the first sentence.

Comment: My question is why the compiler or the JLS are designed that way for static methods hiding, if static methods belong always to a class, and that class can always be inferred at compile time, I can't see the real need for return-type covariance checking in that specific case. My question is not about how the things work with the current compiler, but why is the JLS written that way in §8.4.8.3.

Comment: I see. @bayou.io explains it nicely I didn't actually see the intricacies of it before - it may indeed be a design oversight to treat static method inheritance behavior like that of instance ones, but uniform treatment makes for less to be aware of also.